# Fedora 16 strange /tmp permissions: mysqld will not start

Tags: fedora, mysql, systemd, bugs

I installed mysql on a brand-new Fedora 16 server and it would not start. This is the line from the log file (`^G` and all):

```
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibNPyIlu' (Errcode: 13)
```

I looked at `/tmp/` and it has rather strange-looking permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwt.
```

Why the dot?  `chmod 1777` does not change anything.  Is this responsible for the error?  What's next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug with `mysqld` starting with `systemd` when they made a change to use ServicesPrivateTmp for additional security. When you performed a `yum update`, the `mysql` package was updated to mysql-5.5.22-1.fc16 or greater which corrected the issue.

- [Bug 815812](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=815812)
- [Bug 782513](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=782513)
- [Description of Fedora's implementation of 'PrivateTmp' feature](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp)

Answer (score 5):

The dot means there is an ACL (access control list) overriding the usual Unix permission scheme. Here's what mine looks like:

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 7 root root 4096 Apr 23 22:36 /tmp

$ getfacl /tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Check your /tmp directory. If it differs, use setfacl to correct it.

Comment: Thanks!  This is new.  :-)  I should dig around to learn more about it.  This was not the cause for my problem in the end, but what a nice piece of knowledge!

Comment: No, the dot means the opposite.  A `+` means there are extended ACLs.

Comment: `getfacl` is showing you the file has only minimal ACLs.  See http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/

Answer (score 5):

Error 13 is probably system error 13, which means permission denied.

```
$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

A dot means the file has an SELinux context.

[GNU coreutils - What information is listed](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed)

> GNU ls uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with an SELinux security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is marked with a ‘+’ character.

You can display the SELinux context by running `ls -Z`, e.g.

```
$ ls -dZ /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /tmp
```

Next steps are:

- look in `/var/log/messages`
- look in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`
- try running `ausearch` or `sealert`

See:

- [Security-Enhanced Linux Troubleshooting](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html)
- [Searching For and Viewing Denials](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Searching_For_and_Viewing_Denials.html)

Comment: See uther's answer too.  That might be the root cause for your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

**SELinux can be tricky to configure with MySQL**

Fedora and Red Hat are using SELinux (see in /etc/sysconfig/selinux if SELINUX has a value of "enforcing"). I had installed (2 years ago) MySQL on RHEL 5 and I had to tweak SELinux so it would play nicely with MySQL.

If it is not an ACL permission deny (like sugested by Barry Brown) then try to look if by setting SELINUX to "permissive" (and rebooting) this does not solve your problem. Setting SELinux to permissive will not deny a process the access it requests, but it will be still logged. So if SELinux is the culprit, you will get informed in the logs and MySQL will anyway be able to start.

If it did solve your problem but you want to keep SELinux activated, look for SELinux+MySQL+Fedora, I had found plenty of resources 2 years ago on this matter. Things might have changed since that time and might depends on MySQL versions, etc. So I cannot give you better advice than pointing you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem did not have to do with permissions - though I was thrilled to get the answer above to satisfy my curiosity.  Instead, I discovered that I had not run

```
 yum update
```

after the initial Fedora installation.  I guess, the bug got fixed somewhere in there after the original release of Fedora 16.  Duh.